# How to group minutes with 15-mins interval

Tags: r

I have a data frame with date , name and values ,here some of the dates are in 15-mins interval and some are not , how to get average by grouping that are not in 15-mins in to regular intervals  eg. if min lies between 0-14 then 15min, 15-29 then 15 mins ,30-44 then 30 mins , 45-59 then 45 mins

```
df  
date_time            name         value  
2014-02-01 00:01:00   sam          23  
2014-02-01 00:14:00   sam          24  
2014-02-01 01:00:00   sam          24  
2014-02-01 01:15:00   sam          12  
2014-02-01 01:30:00   sam          27  
2014-02-01 01:45:00   sam          20  
2014-02-01 02:00:00   sunny        23  
2014-02-01 02:15:00   sunny        33  
2014-02-01 02:17:00   sunny        41  
2014-02-01 02:30:00   sunny        23  
2014-02-01 02:46:00   sunny        43  

o/p
date_time             name         value  
2014-02-01  00:00:00    sam     23.5  
2014-02-01  01:00:00    sam     24  
2014-02-01  01:15:00    sam     12  
2014-02-01  01:30:00    sam     27  
2014-02-01  01:45:00    sam     20  
2014-02-01  02:00:00    sunny   23  
2014-02-01  02:15:00    sunny   37  
2014-02-01  02:30:00    sunny   23  
2014-02-01  02:45:00    sunny   43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant that if min lies between 0-14 then new variable should be 0min rather than 15min. If so, here's my suggestion:

```
newvar <- floor(as.numeric(format(dt$date_time, "%M"))/15)*15
```

I'm supposing that your `date_time` has `POSIX` format. Otherwise, you just need to make a simple conversion before using my solution.

Comment: Thanls that works and now how to replace old minutes with this new minutes

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste0(as.character(format(dt$date_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:")),newvar,as.character(format(dt$date_time,":%S"))))`